# How to replace the Space with UnderScore( _ ) in the array in objective C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, ipad

How to replace the Space with UnderScore( _ ) in the array in objective C.
The following is the code i am using to read the array data from the file,

```
NSString *g = [[NSString alloc]initWithCString:data];
    NSMutableString *tempGetAll = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    if(k>0){
        NSArray *lines = [g componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@""]];
        for (NSString* line in lines)
        {
          //[arrGetAll addObject: line];
          NSLog(@"%@",line) ;
          //NSLog(@"---------");

        }

    }
    k++;
```

The following is the output i am getting,

hi how r u 20.000

But i need the output in the following way,

hi_how_r_u:20.000

so how to replace the space with the Underscore.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a method `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:`

```
NSString* string1 = @"123 123 123";
NSString* string2 = [string1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"_"];
NSLog(@"%@", string2);
```

Result is

> 123_123_123

Comment: Hi beryllium, thanks for the help, I am able replace the space with the underscore, But i am also getting a underscore before the value once,i.e,  _123_123_123

Comment: I suggest you have space before your string. Simply remove it if you don't need it

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a string from an array by joining its elements you must use NSArray's:

```
- (NSString *)componentsJoinedByString:(NSString *)separator
```

In your case it is:

```
NSString *getAll = [lines componentsJoinedByString:@"_"];
```

Essentially "componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet" splits a string to an array, "componentsJoinedByString" joins array components in one string.